# String to Hashtable

Tags: java, string, hashtable

I wrote a simple program which reads IpTables log results , remove 90% of the output , and what is left is:

```
192.168.1.1 152
192.168.1.1 17485
192.168.1.1 5592
```

Where, the first column contains source IP , the second one destination Port. Those values are stored in a string. I would like to transfer the values from that string to a Hashtable, but I don't have any idea how.

```
Hashtable<String, String> IpDpt = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        hmIpDpt.put(IP1,DPT1);
        hmIpDpt.put(IP1,DPT2);
        hmIpDpt.put(IP1,DPT3);
        hmIpDpt.put(IP2,DPT4);
```

Comment: Use a HashMap instead..Hashtable was deprecated long ago...

Answer (score 3):

if you transferred to `hashtable` then you will not have all the logs available because `hashtable` does not allows duplicate values and in your log there may be chances of duplicate values . so `hashtable` overrides values.

Comment: This is not exactly an answer though.

Comment: Please add this as a hint in the comments section.

Answer (score 2):

Try this program.

```
String info = "192.168.1.1 152";
    Hashtable<String, List<String>> IpDpt = new Hashtable<String, List<String>>();
    String[] values = info.split( " " );
    String key = values[0];
    String value = values[1];
    if ( IpDpt.containsKey( key ) )
        IpDpt.get( key ).add( value );
    else
        IpDpt.put( key, new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList( value ) ) );
```

To check whether the key has at least 100 values

```
if(IpDpt.containsKey( key ) && IpDpt.get( key ).size() >=100) 
{ 
    // business logic here 
}
```

Comment: I should be reading my results live from a string , and deciding whether one 1 IP address is checking more than 100 ports on my machine... So the values from the string should go the the hasmap and I should check wheter the key has at least 100 values.

Comment: You can put extra check to check if the key has at least 100 values.

if(IpDpt.containsKey( key ) && IpDpt.get( key ).size() >100)
{
  // business logic here
}

Comment: Also you can replace List with Set if there are duplicate entries for the port number with same IP address. Like 192.168.1.1 152 entry is multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

For every line you read, split the string on space like that:

```
    String line = "192.168.1.1 152";
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
    you_map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
```

That should do it.

Comment: But this does not allow n:m mappings of IPs to ports. Note that the same IP address might appear multiple times!

Answer (score 0):

A Map cannot hold multiple values per key. So you should either use a third party library that offers something like a `MultiMap`, or use a `Set` to hold the values:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> ipToPortMap = new HashMap<>();

public void addEntry(String ip, String port) {
    Set<String> ports = ipToPortMap.get(ip);
    if (ports == null) {
        ports = new HashSet<>();
        ipToPortMap.put(ip, ports);
    }

    ports.add(port);
}
```

Now just iterate over your input (maybe using a `Scanner`) and call `addEntry`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Guava `Multimap` to allow duplicate key.

```
  Multimap<String,String> multimap=ArrayListMultimap.create();

  //put your ips and port.
```